# How can I add a ribbon menu to an existing MFC application?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, ribbon, mfc-feature-pack

Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Feature Pack has ribbon menu support. Is it possible to make use of that in an existing MFC application that was not created with a ribbon menu?

Comment: I've found an interesting information about your question.
hope it helps. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983935.aspx

Comment: Yes, it is! I did one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It certainly is possible to take an existing MFC application and update it to use the ribbon in the MFC Feature Pack, and I've done this myself.

There are a couple of walkthrough articles on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982451.aspx) that show how to do it, using the Scribble MFC sample application that you may be familiar with.

In essence, what you need to do is change your code to use the Feature Pack base classes instead of the standard MFC base classes - for example, replace `CWinApp` with `CWinAppEx`, `CFrameWnd` with `CFrameWndEx`, etc. Then you can add `CMFCRibbonBar` and `CMFCRibbonApplicationButton` objects to your main window class to create the ribbon itself. To get started I'd suggest downloading the Scribble sample and following the walkthough articles.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the resources pointed out by ChrisN, I recommend creating a new MFC application that includes a ribbon and examining the generated code..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is surely possible to use the ribbon classes provided with the MFC Feature Pack.

A basic introduction is available here: [Quick Tour Of New MFC Functionality](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2007/11/09/quick-tour-of-new-mfc-functionality.aspx) and a more detailed tutorial can be found here: [MFC Feature Pack Tutorial](http://nibuthomas.com/tutorial_mfc_feature_pack1_part1/).

However, be aware that there is a rather strict license attached to it. For the conditions see [Licensing the 2007 Microsoft Office User Interface](http://blogs.msdn.com/jensenh/archive/2006/11/21/licensing-the-2007-microsoft-office-user-interface.aspx) and this [related discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563312/is-the-ms-ribbon-office-ui-license-worth-worrying-about) on SO.